# How to use mongodb from Lua 5.3 in OS X?

Tags: lua

I want to use mongodb from Lua 5.3 script in OS X. I found a project luamongo. Unfortunately I could not build it and I am not sure it is support Lua 5.3.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Which luamongo? There are a few in github for instance. What errors did you get?

Comment: I tried moai/luamongo and get error "Package lua5.3 was not found in the pkg-config search path. Perhaps you should add the directory containing 'lua5.3.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable No package 'lua5.3' found".